# Как реализовать layout для сообщений в чате?

Tags: java, android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как правильно реализовать такое?

```
<LinearLayout
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_chat_left">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/chatTextLeft"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
                android:paddingVertical="10dp"
                android:paddingStart="7dp"
                android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                android:text="Lorem Ipsum has been like"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/chatTimeLeft"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/chatTextLeft"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_light"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="12:11 AM"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="14sp" />


        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Когда я пытаюсь сделать все время текст или лезет на время или не доходит до конца.

Comment: Просто сделать не выйдет. Попробуйте тут пример посмотреть: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62263032/3212712

Comment: Я по аналогии делаю через RecyclerView и в нем применяю для каждой строки свой layout, где рисую как мне нравится